# Is it documented that the four numeric fields of a C# app are each of type UNSIGNED16?

Tags: .net-core

I have an app which builds successfully using this command:

```
dotnet build /p:Version=1.2.3.65534 LicenseReporter.csproj
```

But if I build it using this very slightly different command:

```
dotnet build /p:Version=1.2.3.65535 LicenseReporter.csproj
```

…then there's a build time error:

> T:\Development\License Reporter\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\LicenseReporter.AssemblyInfo.cs(20,55): error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]] [T:\Development\License Reporter\LicenseReporter.csproj]

Is the type used for each of the four numeric version fields fixed as UNSIGNED16 or can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data type is fixed. See the documentation of the [VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource#parameters):

> The version consists of two 32-bit integers, defined by four 16-bit integers.